# I want to implement a Youtube video in my HTML code

Tags: html, css, video, youtube

I want to implement a Youtube video, but the video didn't show, even if i think i wrote the code correctly.

I am confused because i copy pasted a code from another html code, and just when i change the URL video to another one, it didn't show the new video anymore...

```html
<iframe width="854" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com    /watch?v=6kg2yV_3B1Q" frameborder="0" gesture="media" allow="encrypted-media"     allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

code to the codepen : https://codepen.io/Peyo5202/pen/RwbGaGm?editors=1000

No error message, just a blank space instead of the video.

Comment: You need to change the url to the `embed` endpoint

Answer (score 0):

this is a trivial thing check this [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_youtube.asp), best of luck, try this

```
    <iframe width="420" height="315"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY">
</iframe>
```

Comment: "Link only" answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow.  Consider adding a comment instead, or providing a more detailed explanation for some code.

Comment: i've got a notification that it's a new member, so i provide the link for the description, BTW thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

try with this link instead of your link for a test, it will work :

```
<iframe width="420" height="315"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY"
</iframe>
```

So I think your link has a problem

Answer (score 0):

You should embed iframe tag from youtube:
- Hit the share button
- Choose embed HTML
The iframe tag should looks like this:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6kg2yV_3B1Q" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```